# Everybody marries Rochel and wakes up to Leah

Tags: sources-mekorot, marriage, shidduchim-dating, shalom-bayit

I think I heard this from Rabbi Jacobson, a lecturer in theyeshiva.net but I don't recall where. In [this lecture](https://www.theyeshiva.net/item/183) (minutes 39 to 47), he mentions it again:

That everybody has expectations in his wife before he marries her and after he marries her she is more realistic and this is learned from Yakov who married the beautiful Rachel and woke up to Leah

What is the source of this teaching?
If it is not accurate please correct it.

Comment: This question would be more compelling and answerable if you'd [edit] in as much information as you can about where you've heard of this concept.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I can not find it , the closest thing I found was  minute 39 and 47 https://www.theyeshiva.net/item/183 (I think I heard it the first time also from Rabbi Jacobson)

Comment: Please [edit] in something like "I think I heard this from Rabbi Jacobson, a lecturer in Yeshivas Torah Umitzvos and noted expert in the field of marriage, but I don't recall where. In [this lecture](http://example.net) (minutes 39 to 47), he mentions a similar concept, related to business partnerships:  '... as we see from Yaakov Avinu and Rachel Imeinu, don't go into a relationship expecting to ...'" In other words, *as much information as you can*.

Comment: @IsaacMoses I did a little (some of what you wrote I do not know and do not want to  write myself, fell free to add it yourself). Thank you for the mentoring

Comment: Does he actually mention this concept in that interval? If so, why not just quote him verbatim? It doesn't really matter where you've heard it first; the point is to establish why anyone ought to think this concept may exist in Judaism such that it's worth someone's time to try to track down a traditional source. If this lecture is the most notable instance of this claim you're aware of, then linking to it and quoting it verbatim is a very  good foundation for the question. Even better would be if you could say who this Rabbi or website is, answering the implicit question "Why should I care?"

Comment: Seems strange. Women don't have preconceived expectations before marriage?

Comment: @IsaacMoses if you want me to write up what he is saying I can. I personally, in this case, do not think someone should care about it  because of who said it  , only on its own merits

Comment: @hazoriz The fact that it's a meritorious idea has little to do with whether there's likely to be a traditional source for it. The reason you think there may be a source is that you've heard it from someone whom you believe would likely only make such a claim based on traditional sources. That's also the best indication you have available for anyone else to think that there may be a source to look for.

Comment: @user6591 I don't think the underlying concept of this teaching is meant to be gender specific.

Comment: @IsaacMoses you are right

Comment: Obviously one gets to know a person better after marriage, just as any interaction between two people will allow them to get to know each other better. This goes without saying. If someone related this to Rahel and Leah, it was probably just a cute derash to emphasise the obvious. Why would you think that this fact isnt obvious?

Comment: Ya know, this sounds a lot like it might be a great start to a joke.

Comment: Why do you assume there’s a source to this, besides common sense that nobody can predict the future or know *everything* about his wife before getting to know her better? I’m with @mevaqesh - this just looks like a cute derash to prove a point.

Comment: @DonielF I want to repeat it, but only if it has a better source that is why I asked